# implicitly_wait VS. time_sleep() in Selenium 3.0.2 Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to implement a simple sub dowloader with Selenium on Python 2.7 going on the http://www.yifysubtitles.com website.

I have run into serious troubles with implementing waits either implicit or explicit in Selenium - surely caused by ignorance rather than code.

I eventually opted for the destroy-all `time.sleep()` solution. The program works but I would like a more programatic solution and a prettier code.

Here is the code with the both implicit and explicit waits:

```
user_input = raw_input("Enter the movie of interest: ")

profile = SetProfile()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
# browser.implicitly_wait(30)
WindowSize(400, 400)
browser.get(url)

print "Searching..."
search_bar = browser.find_element_by_id("qSearch")
click_button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("glyphicon")

#wait_1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 50)
#cookie_element = wait_1.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"cc_btn.cc_btn_accept_all")))

time.sleep(5)

accept_cookies_btn = browser.find_element_by_class_name("cc_btn.cc_btn_accept_all")
search_bar.clear()
accept_cookies_btn.click()

search_bar.send_keys(user_input)
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(10)

#wait_2 = WebDriverWait(browser, 50)
#result_element = wait_2.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.media-heading")))

result = browser.find_element_by_class_name("media-heading")
result.click()

print "Movie found!"
time.sleep(10)

req = requests.get(browser.current_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
link_to_sub = ResultParser(soup)

print "Choosing the best eng. subtitle..."

browser.get(url+link_to_sub[1])

download_button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-icon")
download_button.click()

time.sleep(10)

browser.quit()

print "Enjoy!"
```

I have commented out the waits (explicit or implicit) I tried to use. Indeed, If I use waits instead `time.sleep`, Selenium will throw at me an `ElementNotVisibleException`.

Thus, am I doing something wrong with the waits? 
Regarding the implicit waits, Selenium always throws at me `ElementNotVisibleException: Message:`  (With message empty) when I run the program, whatever the wait length (tried 5, 30 and 100!).

When I use explicit waits, similarly, Selenium either throw `ElementNotVisibleException` or seems to use the DOM from the preceding page. Indeed, in the last case the wait is after clicking on the result, but I get the heading of the previous page...

As I said, when I use `time.sleep()`, Selenium finds the elements without any trouble.

A long message for a simple question: why my waits seem to not work?

Comment: You'd need to provide the code that includes that waits that don't work for us to help you with why the waits don't work.

Comment: Aren't the uncommented waits sufficient for it? I thought to decomment them so that to have just one piece of code including the possible waits I have included so far

Comment: You are right... I was ignoring the comments and didn't see that they contained the waits. Sorry.